# R finding the average order interval (number of days)

Tags: r, for-loop

My goal is to obtain the average number of days it takes for a given product to be purchased. If Product_A is purchased three times over a given period ('2012-12-01','2012-12-05,'2012-12-10') then our average order interval will be the average of 4 & 5 - 4.5 days.

I wrote a For Loop to calculate the interval between two points (I can use the aggregate function to calculate my mean or median by product) but I keep getting a length error. This is supposed to be a scale-able solution

Here is a sample dataframe:

```
product_info <- data.frame(productId = c("A", "A", "A", "B","B","B"), 
                           order_date = c("2014-05-01", "2014-05-05", "2014-05-10", "2014-06-01","2014-06-07", "2014-06-18"), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

Here is my code:

```
 for (i in 2:length(unique(product_info$productId))){
  if(product_info$productId[i]==product_info$productId[i-1]){
    product_info$interval[i] <- as.integer(difftime(product_info$order_date[i],product_info$order_date[i-1]))
  }
}
```

My desired output should be:

```
product_info <- data.frame(productId = c("A", "A", "A", "B","B","B"), 
                           order_date = c("2014-05-01", "2014-05-05", "2014-05-10", "2014-06-01","2014-06-07", "2014-06-18"), 
                           interval= c("0", "4", "5", "0","6","11"), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

Any help would be very much appreciated.

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try

```
  product_info$order_date <- as.Date(product_info$order_date)

  product_info$interval <- with(product_info, ave(as.numeric(order_date), 
                  productId, FUN=function(x) c(0, diff(x))))
  product_info
  productId order_date interval
1         A 2014-05-01        0
2         A 2014-05-05        4
3         A 2014-05-10        5
4         B 2014-06-01        0
5         B 2014-06-07        6
6         B 2014-06-18       11
```

Or using `data.table`

```
 library(data.table)#v1.9.5+
 setDT(product_info)[,interval := c(0, diff(as.Date(order_date))) , productId]
```

If the 'order_date' is not ordered, we have to 'order` it before doing the 'diff'

```
 setDT(product_info)[, order_date:= as.Date(order_date)
           ][order(order_date), interval :=as.numeric(order_date -
           shift(order_date, fill=order_date[1L])) , by = productId]
 #    productId order_date interval
 #1:         A 2014-05-01        0
 #2:         A 2014-05-05        4
 #3:         A 2014-05-10        5
 #4:         B 2014-06-01        0
 #5:         B 2014-06-07        6
 #6:         B 2014-06-18       11
```

Comment: This works. Just for readers who will like to use this in the future, you have to sort the dataframe first by productId and order_date, regardless of the solution you're using. Thx Akrun.

Answer (score 2):

Convert to date format -

```
product_info$order_date <- as.Date(product_info$order_date)
```

Using `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)
product_info %>% group_by(productId) %>%
                 mutate(interval=c(0,diff(order_date))
```

Comment: Thx for the help Jeremy. This solution also works very well.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a `dplyr` solution. You first want to convert to the date format, then ordering by the date, grouping by product and finally adding the column which is the difference between the last two days within this product. Note that the 0 days have been replaced with `NA` which IMHO is more applicable than `0`.

```
library(dplyr)
product_info <- product_info %>%
    mutate(order_date=as.Date(order_date)) %>%
    arrange(order_date) %>%
    group_by(productId) %>%
    mutate(interval=order_date-lag(order_date))

product_info
  productId order_date interval
1         A 2014-05-01  NA days
2         A 2014-05-05   4 days
3         A 2014-05-10   5 days
4         B 2014-06-01  NA days
5         B 2014-06-07   6 days
6         B 2014-06-18  11 days
```